# Failing script as process substitution not working in Dart

Tags: bash, flutter, dart, unix, sh

Is there any way to make the script:

`diff <(echo 'hello') <(echo 'hello-2')`

work, as currently it fails with error in Dart when run using `Process.run` or `Process.start`:

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

I tried to drill down on it and found out that since process substitution is not available when running the script through `Process.run` or `Process.start`, hence it's failing. So, is there any way to make it work?

I found out that we need to use `set +o posix` to make process substitution available if it's not, but I don't know how to do it in Dart.

Comment: I don't think its an `yq` issue, if it works as expected on the command line. You probably need to check with the melos part

Comment: Yep, I found out about the root cause and have updated the question. Trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: @Aakash did you find the solution?

Comment: Yes, so I wrapped the command in double quotes and it worked.

Comment: @Aakash not quite sure that I understood which part) do you have a code sample maybe?)

Comment: Pls try this: `"diff <(echo 'hello') <(echo 'hello-2')"`

Comment: If that worked, it's because you ran it on a system where `sh` is a symlink to Bash, not because of any particular quoting.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.2/dart-io/Process/start.html) and common expectations, the shell will be `/bin/sh`; and so, you can't use Bash features like process substitutions.

You can always force it by running Bash explicitly:

```dart
Process.run("bash", ["-c", "diff <(echo 'hello') <(echo 'hello-2')"])
```

You could add `set +o posix;` to the beginning of the argument to `bash -c` (the argument can be an arbitrarily complex string with multiple commands) but of course, it's not necessary here, and actually a red herring in this context.

Here's an example of a slightly more complex command which uses the Bash-only "C-style" `for` loop syntax.

```
Process.run("bash", ["-c", "for ((i=0; i<=255; i++)); do ping -c 3 10.9.8.$i || break; done; echo 'finished'"])
```

... though generally speaking, it's probably better to keep your subprocesses as simple as possible, and write any necessary plumbing in the host language.

Perhaps see also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)